# DataTable doesn't work if columns don't match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, datatables

I have a table with one row which is displayed and another one which is hidden, but displayed onclick.

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="datatable" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 1300px; margin-bottom: 50px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>8</th>
            <th>9</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>#</td>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>3</td>
           <td>4</td>
           <td>5</td>
           <td>6</td>
           <td>8</td>
           <td>9</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td colspan="9" id="break_{{$t->BreakID}}" style="display: none;"></td>
       </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

DataTable functionality works if I remove this row:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="9" id="break_{{$t->BreakID}}" style="display: none;"></td>
</tr>
```

Or If I add 8 td's to match the th from previous row, but then it looks ugly. I need one td which is `colspan = 9`. I've also tried to add 8 td's with hidden display style. Also it didn't work out.

Otherwise it doesn't work and produces an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the same amount of columns in every row, including headers.
If the last row should not have all columns covered. You should try and hide the unwanted `<td>`s with CSS.

I don't think what you want is possible with DataTables unless a plugin exists for it. In their manual they do have something about 'row grouping', but I guess they meant 'cell grouping' instead of [Row grouping](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html)? Anyway in the example the amount of td's match with the rest of the table.

Comment: I did.. I tried to add 8 tds with `<td style="display:none;"></td>` but it is not working.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a picture how it looked with the hidden cells? It might be because of the table or parent row still having styles applied.

Comment: It works but first 20 pages are empty... And it is written `Showing 181 to 190 of 398 entries`.

Comment: edited my answer, but don't think it is possible the easy way

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this affects, but you have 10 cells in the first row, and 9 cells in the second and in the third.

Comment: Ah that's just what he wants if I read the question correctly :p

Comment: I thought he wanted 10, 10, and 10 but spanned. Moreover, the display:none should go on the row.

Comment: Like I said in comment in previous question. It works but firt 20 pages are empty and then results come.

Answer (score 0):

Data-table need all the fields which you define and after loading or data fetching you can hide the particular column using data-table's function

like this in js file

usercheck is my user role checking variable.

```
if (usercheck == 3)
{
    data_table.column(6).visible(false);//data_table is variable of data-table and here is the code to hide column in data-table
}
```

you have to hide particular column base on condition.